# CoreData values accidentally changing

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am having an issue with core data values changing when I do not intend them to. I have an idea about how to fix it but every time I do that I get unrecognized selector. My idea is to change `valueArray = attribute.values;` to `valueArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:attribute.values];` Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I am trying to create a sum total of the attribute.values. I have skill nodes and each has attributes attached to it and sometimes those attribute values are different. I am trying to sum up all of the like values.

```
    Build *selectedBuild = [buildListController selectedObjects][0];
    NSMutableDictionary *attributeAggregator = nil;
    attributeAggregator = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSLog(@"Before: %@", attributeAggregator);
    NSMutableDictionary *numValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSArray *valueArray = nil;

    for (SkillNode *active in selectedBuild.activeNodes) {
        for (Attribute *attribute in active.attributes) {
            NSString *attrName = attribute.name;
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", attribute.name, attribute.values);
            NSMutableArray *obj = [attributeAggregator objectForKey:attribute.name];
            if (obj) {
                for (int ndx = 0; ndx < [obj count]; ndx++) {
                    obj[ndx] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([obj[ndx] integerValue] + [attribute.values[ndx] integerValue])];
                }
                [attributeAggregator setValue:obj forKey:attrName];
            } else {
                valueArray = attribute.values;
                [attributeAggregator setValue:valueArray forKey:attrName];
                [numValues setValue:attribute.numValues forKey:attrName];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the unrecognized selector error?

Comment: sending a message to a deallocated object. It can't find the object in memory that was specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code is scary.

```
if (obj) {
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < [obj count]; ndx++) {
        obj[ndx] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([obj[ndx] integerValue] + [attribute.values[ndx] integerValue])];
    }
[attributeAggregator setValue:obj forKey:attrName];
```

You are iterating over `obj` and mutating it at the same time, which is dangerous and frowned upon. Which is why fast-enumeration for loops don't even compile when you do this.

Check into using [KVC Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) to get your sum, I am not clear enough on what your data structure is to show you how, but take a look at the documentation, specifically `@sum`

**RE: Comments**

Ok, I was definitely not clear on what exactly you are doing. The collection operator isn't going to help you here. But, I still wouldn't mutate the array as you're iterating over it. I'd likely just add the two arrays into a new one, then set the resultant array where you want it when finished. Example of summing two arrays using a third resultant array...

```
NSArray *foo = @[@1, @2, @3];
NSArray *bar = @[@4, @5, @6];

NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[foo count]];

[foo enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   result[idx] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[obj integerValue] + [bar[idx] integerValue]];
}];

// result == @[@5, @7, @9]
```

Comment: The data structure is like this: {1, 2, 4}. The array being added is {3, 5, 6} and when added together the way I am wanting gives you this: {4, 7, 10}. I understand why mutating at the same time as iteration is dangerous but since I know the data will always be formatted this way I felt it was 'ok' in a loose sense.

Comment: If there is a better way and safer way to do it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the attribute.values into an NSArray before adding it to your dictionary, why don't you simply add attributes.values to your dictionary?

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
...
valueArray = attribute.values;
[attributeAggregator setValue:valueArray forKey:attrName];
...
```

Change that to:

```
...
[attributeAggregator setValue:attribute.values forKey:attrName];
...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: same results as before, the value that is stored just keeps changing.

Comment: Ah! I see what's going on now... You're rewriting the same key in that dictionary with a different value every time. What are you trying to do exactly? Append `attribute.values` to what's already existing in the dictionary?

Comment: I am trying to create a sum total of the attribute.values. I have skill nodes and each has attributes attached to it and sometimes those attribute values are different. I am trying to sum up all of the like values.

Comment: Anything else I might have left out in my description?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making a mutableCopy of the attribute.values and storing that in the dictionary.